# Help with JOINs in query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT * FROM
Table_A
LEFT JOIN Table_B
 ON (Table_A.A_ID = Table_B.A_ID)
INNER JOIN Table_C ON (Table_C.C_ID = Table_B.C_ID)
WHERE Table_A.ID = 3
```

This returns 0 rows, currently.

How can I set this up so I always get Table_A, even if there is no row for Table_B or Table_C.  I still want to maintain the  INNER JOIN between Table_B and Table_C, so that I will never get a B without a C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sub query the Table B and Table C. e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_A 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * 
         FROM Table_B
         INNER JOIN Table_C ON (Table_C.C_ID = Table_B.C_ID)
    ) B_AND_C ON (Table_A.A_ID = B_AND_C.A_ID)
WHERE Table_A.ID = 3
```

Answer (score 2):

You may not have to use an inline view. I'm not  in front of a machine with MySQL right now so I can't check but you can try

```
SELECT *
FROM table_A a 
LEFT JOIN (table_B b 
    INNER JOIN table_C c
    ON b.c_id = c.c_id)
ON a.b_id = b.b_id
WHERE 
    a.a_id =3
```

Comment: This should work, if such syntax is allowed in MySQL. (And based on [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), it should be).

Comment: I upvoted your answer.  I actually ended up just opting for a LEFT JOIN btw.. because of a FK constraint I always get B and C together.. and its simpler just to LEFT JOIN twice